# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IdempotentRepository must be configured when using readLock=idempotent

Tags: apache-camel, hazelcast

**I need complete implemention of idempotentRepository in clustered environment.**
My current implementation is as below, It is throwing error for implementation of idempotentRepository

```
<route id="request" >
                <from uri="file:someFolderLocation?readLock=idempotent&amp;readLockRemoveOnCommit=true"/>
               <to uri="file: someOtherFolderLocation "/>
```

> I am using camel over a clustered environment and want to use a
>   readlock on my file consumer endpoint. The only cluster safe readlock
>   is the idempotent readlock however this requires an
>   idempotentRepository to be set on the file uri.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IdempotentRepository must be configured when using readLock=idempotent
       at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileEndpoint.doStart(GenericFileEndpoint.java:1328)
       at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
       at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:3269)
       at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doAddService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1243)
       at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1204)
       at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1200)
       at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:584)
       ... 40 more
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have shared filesystem, you can use FileIdempotentRepository, hope it works for you.

readLockRemoveOnCommit=true  - This option allows to specify whether to remove the file name entry from the idempotent repository when processing the file succeeded and a commit happens.

readLockRemoveOnRollback=true -This option allows to specify whether to remove the file name entry from the idempotent repository when processing the file failed and a rollback happens.

Following is the implementation of FileIdempotentRepository

```
<bean id="myFileStore" class="org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.FileIdempotentRepository"> 
               <property name="fileStore" value="/shared/myFileStore.txt"/> 
               <property name="maxFileStoreSize" value="512000000"/> 
               <property name="cacheSize" value="100000"/> 
    </bean>
        <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
           <route id="request" >
                <from uri="file:someFolderLocation?readLock=idempotent&amp;idempotentRepository=#myFileStore&amp;readLockRemoveOnCommit=true&amp;readLockRemoveOnRollback=true/>
                <to uri="file: someOtherFolderLocation "/>
           </route>
         </camelContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation about that available there http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Please read sections:

- Using a file based idempotent repository (probably will not work in most clusters as it will require some shared filesystem like nfs/gluster)
- Using a JPA based idempotent repository (can fit your requirements)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

HazelcastIdempotentRepository is one of the best way to implement for shared File system in clustered environment.

**Camel Route:**

```
<from uri="file:///var/opt/irs/message?delete=true&amp;readLock=idempotent&amp;idempotentRepository=#idempotentRepo&amp;readLockLoggingLevel=WARN&amp;shuffle=true&amp;delay=5000" />
<to uri="send.file" />
```

w.r.t the requirement, configure 
readLockRemoveOnCommit=true and readLockRemoveOnRollback=true in camel route.

sort the files by random to reduce the chance of multiple nodes trying to access the same file.

**IdempotentRepository Bean:**

This bean defines a Camel idempotent repository based on hazelcast, which ensures that files are collected by only one file endpoint when the same inputendpoint is running on more than one server.

```
     @Autowired
    @Qualifier("hazelcastRepo")
    private HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;


        @Bean(name = "idempotentRepo")
        public IdempotentRepository<String> myIdempotentRepo() {

            return new HazelcastIdempotentRepository(hazelcastInstance, "hazelMap");
        }
```

**Eviction strategy:**

To clean hazelcast, I would recommend Eviction strategy. It has also plenty of other options to clean Repository. In my case the below hazelcast configuration worked very well.
Configure time-to-live-seconds= x sec in hazelcast-context.xml or hazelcast-default.xml.

```
<map name="hazelMap" 
                time-to-live-seconds="60"
                max-idle-seconds="0"
                eviction-policy="LRU"           
                eviction-percentage="0"
                max-size="0"
                min-eviction-check-millis="100"/>
```

To get more information,I Would like to recommand the Camel in Action: Idempotency document:[Idempotency](http://freecontent.manning.com/camel-in-action-idempotency/)